# Borrar un objeto en específico de un archivo .dat en Java

Tags: java, poo

intento hacer un método que me permita eliminar un objeto "persona" de un archivo .dat, creando un archivo temporal y escribiendo todos los objetos que no tengan el nombre que busco eliminar, sin embargo me arroja una excepción y no consigo arreglarla

Este es el código de el método:

```
public static void BorrarLinea() {     
        File archivo = new File("C:\\Users\\spore\\Documents\\Codigo Binario\\personal.dat");
           File archivotemp = new File("C:\\Users\\spore\\Documents\\Codigo Binario\\personaltemp.dat");
       try {
           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(archivo);
           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(archivotemp);
           ObjectOutputStream escribir = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
           ObjectInputStream leer = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
           Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
           
           String nombre;
           boolean encontrado = false;
           
           System.out.println("Dame el nombre que deseas eliminar de la lista.");
           nombre=entrada.nextLine();
    
                   
           while (fis.available() > 0) {    
               Persona personaLeida = (Persona) leer.readObject();
                if (personaLeida.getNombre().equals(nombre)) {
                    System.out.println("Usuario eliminado");
                    encontrado = true;
                   
                } else {
                    escribir.writeObject(personaLeida);
                        }      
                }
           
           if (!encontrado) {System.out.println("La persona no existe.");}
           } catch (FileNotFoundException FNF) {System.out.println("Archivo no encontrado " + FNF.toString());
    
           }catch (IOException ioe) { 
                ioe.printStackTrace();
           }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error al leer el archivo. "+ e.getMessage());   
        } 
       archivo.delete();
       archivotemp.renameTo(archivo);
    }
```

Esta es la excepción que me arroja:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1764)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:509)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:467)
    at archivobinario.MetodosBinarios.BorrarLinea(MetodosBinarios.java:155)
    at archivobinario.MenuArchivo.main(MenuArchivo.java:36)
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por leer la publicación

Comment: No se java.. pero todos los lenguajes funcionan igual con los archivos.. que es available()??? porque veo que fis nunca adelanta su puntero, porque para leer usas otro archivo, con lo cual, puede que hayas terminado de leer el archivo, pero segun tu codigo, no lo sabe?

Answer (score 0):

Pues no he sido capaz de reproducir tu error, no sé si tu problema estará en que no cierras explícitamente los streams que abres, no hay ningún close en tu código para ninguno de esos streams. Como no pones el código con el que escribes en el fichero tampoco puedo asegurar que ahí los estés cerrando.

Para no olvidar ese cierre, hace tiempo que java incluye un instrucción especial: [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Antes de que se introdujera eso había que cerrar los streams asociados a la lectura o escritura de fichero una vez finalizada la operación

```
static String readFirstLineFromFileWithFinallyBlock(String path) throws IOException {

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    try {
        return br.readLine();
    } finally {
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    }
}
```

Ahora puedes reemplazar el código de arriba por este otro más sencillo

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

Si aplicamos esta optimización a tu código, quedaría

```
public class ModificarFichero {

private static final String FICHERO_PERSONAL = "[mi_ruta]";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File archivo = new File(FICHERO_PERSONAL);
    File archivotemp = new File(FICHERO_PERSONAL + "_tmp");

    boolean encontrado = false;

    try (ObjectOutputStream escribir = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(archivotemp));
         ObjectInputStream leer = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(archivo))) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Dame el nombre que deseas eliminar de la lista.");
        String nombre = entrada.nextLine();

        while (true) {
            Persona personaLeida = (Persona) leer.readObject();
            if (personaLeida.getNombre().equals(nombre)) {
                System.out.println("Usuario eliminado");
                encontrado = true;
            } else {
                escribir.writeObject(personaLeida);
            }
        }

    } catch (EOFException eof) {
        if (!encontrado) {
            System.out.println("La persona no existe.");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
        System.out.println("Archivo no encontrado " + fnf.toString());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error al leer el archivo. "+ e.getMessage());
    }

    archivo.delete();
    archivotemp.renameTo(archivo);
}
}
```

El sentencia fis.available estaba funcionando correctamente, pero como no estaba haciendo mucho uso de fis ni fos, no he creado esas variables. Por lo que he podido ver no hay forma de terminar de leer un fichero con ObjectInputStream "de forma elegante", hay que esperar a que salte la excepción EOFException.

Para la próxima, por favor incluye también en tu pregunta cómo estás escribiendo en el fichero, de forma que cualquiera pueda ejecutar tu código y hacer pruebas, lo que se conoce como [un ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Aquí tienes la clase que he usado para escribir en el fichero, por si quieres compararla con la tuya. La clase Persona de prueba que he usado contiene solo dos campos String: nombre y email.

```
public class EscribirFichero {

private static final String FICHERO_PERSONAL = "[mi_ruta]";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Persona> listaPersonas = crearListaPersonas();

    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(FICHERO_PERSONAL))) {
        for(Persona p : listaPersonas) {
            oos.writeObject(p);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static List<Persona> crearListaPersonas() {
    List<Persona> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista.add(new Persona("ricardo", "ricardo@test.com"));
    lista.add(new Persona("juan", "juan@test.com"));
    lista.add(new Persona("nacho", "nacho@test.com"));
    return lista;
}
}
```

Como puedes ver, al escribir he usado la instrucción try-with-resources, que me cierra automáticamente lo que incluya como argumento del try.

```
try ([los recursos que ponga aquí se cerraran al final]) {
  ...
} catch (...) {
}
```