# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar un objeto almacenado en un fichero usando Serialización en java?

Tags: java, archivo, serialización

Estoy realizando una tarea de Gestionar Alumnos donde se pueden añadir alumnos por numero de expediente, y mostrar el listado todo eso lo tengo el problema que estoy teniendo es que al intentar borrar el objeto por número de expediente que lo que hago es escribir todos los que no sean el numero de expediente introducido en un fichero temporal y luego renombrarlo al fichero de alumnos donde esta el listado para que se apliquen los cambios, pero al ejecutar la aplicación tal como lo tengo establecido no elimina el fichero de datos ni renombra el temporal solo me vacía todos los datos teniendo los dos archivos

Código:

```
  private void btnBorrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        int expediente = 0;
        String datosAlumno = "";
        try {
            expediente = Integer.parseInt(textFieldNumExpediente.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            nfe.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "ERROR - FORMÁTO NO VÁLIDO");
        }

        if (selectedFile.exists()) {
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(TemporalFile);
                oos = new MiObjectOutputStream(fos);

                alumno = (Alumno) ois.readObject();

                while (alumno != null) {
                    if (expediente == alumno.getNum_expediente()) {
                        expedienteEncontrado = true;
                    }
                    if (expediente != alumno.getNum_expediente()) {
                        oos.writeObject(alumno);
                        System.out.println("TEMPORAL: " + alumno.getNum_expediente() + " " + alumno.getNombre());
                    }
                    alumno = (Alumno) ois.readObject();

                }
                
            } catch (EOFException eof) {
                if (!expedienteEncontrado) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Nº de Expediente no registrado.");
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
                System.out.println("Fichero no encontrado");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Se ha llegado al final del fichero.");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("Clase no encontrada");
            } finally {

                try {
                    //Flujos de entrada
                    if (ois != null) {
                        ois.close();
                    }
                    if (fis != null) {
                        fis.close();
                    }
                    //Flujos de entrada
                    if (oos != null) {
                        oos.close();
                    }
                    if (fos != null) {
                        fos.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            selectedFile.delete();
            TemporalFile.renameTo(selectedFile);
        }

        if (expedienteEncontrado) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Datos sobre el Nº de Expediente: " + expediente + " borrados correctamente.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Buenas, Andrea, el problema que veo a primera vista es que te estás saltando el primer alumno del fichero siempre, el que lees antes de entra en el while. Nada más comprobar que no es null, lees otro. ¿Qué pasa con él? Por otro lado, creo que ois.readObject lanza una excepción cuando llega al final del fichero, una EOFException, deberías controlarla.

Comment: Hace unos días respondí una pregunta muy parecida a la tuya. Quizás te oriente mi respuesta aparte de lo que te he comentado https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/608599/5896

Comment: @RubioRic Muchas gracias por responderme, he solucionado el error de que me saltaba al primer alumno pero sigo teniendo el problema de que parece que no estoy aplicando bien el rename to ya que el fichero sigue llamandose temporal lo que me hace es eliminarme el fichero donde tengo los datos pero no lo renombra tal como lo tengo.

Comment: Buenas, Andrea, compara tu código con el que te he enlazado arriba. ¿Has capturado la excepción EOFException y puesto el renombrado fuera del try-catch? ¿Has usado try-with-resources de forma que se cierren automáticamente los flujos de entrada y salida? Los de salida no los cierras en tu finally

Comment: Si aplicando todo eso sigue sin funcionarte, actualiza la pregunta y reemplaza tu código original por lo último que tengas

Comment: @RubioRic Lo acabo de editar, ahora el problema es que no me elimina el archivo principal de datos solo me vacía todos los objetos dentro de el que he añadido, ni me renombra el temporal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He cogido tu código, el último que has actualizado, y funciona correctamente. No he sido capaz de reproducir:

> No me elimina el archivo principal de datos solo me vacía todos los
> objetos dentro de el que he añadido, ni me renombra el temporal.

Las únicas diferencias, aparte de que yo leo el número de expediente de la entrada de teclado, son la clase `MiObjectOutputStream` (que no parece necesaria, pues ObjectOutputStream es suficiente) y que yo he nombrado temporalFile con la t minúscula.

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ModificarFicheroOriginal {

    private static final String FICHERO_PERSONAL = "/Users/rubioric/alumnos.dat";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File selectedFile = new File(FICHERO_PERSONAL);
        File temporalFile = new File(FICHERO_PERSONAL + "_tmp");

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;

        boolean expedienteEncontrado = false;
        int numExpediente = 0;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(temporalFile);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Dame el expediente que deseas eliminar de la lista.");
            numExpediente = entrada.nextInt();

            Alumno alumno = (Alumno) ois.readObject();

            while (alumno != null) {
                if (numExpediente == alumno.getNumExpediente()) {
                    expedienteEncontrado = true;
                }
                if (numExpediente != alumno.getNumExpediente()) {
                    oos.writeObject(alumno);
                }
                alumno = (Alumno) ois.readObject();
            }

        } catch (EOFException eof) {
            if (!expedienteEncontrado) {
                System.out.println("Nº de Expediente no registrado: " + numExpediente);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
            System.out.println("Archivo no encontrado " + fnf);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error al leer el archivo. "+ e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                //Flujos de entrada
                if (ois != null) {
                    ois.close();
                }
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
                //Flujos de entrada
                if (oos != null) {
                    oos.close();
                }
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (expedienteEncontrado) {
            System.out.println("Expediente " + numExpediente + "borrado");
        }

        selectedFile.delete();
        temporalFile.renameTo(selectedFile);
    }
}
```

La única peculiaridad que tiene que tener la clase Alumno es que debe implementar Serializable. La clase que yo he usado para la prueba solo tiene dos campos:

```
public class Alumno implements Serializable {
    Integer numExpediente;
    String nombre;
```

Como te indicaba en los comentarios, deberías usar [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), de forma que puedes ahorrarte la parte de cerrar explícitamente los streams, puedes borrar la parte del finally si pones esto al principio de tu try-catch

```
try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(temporalFile));
     ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(selectedFile))) {
```

Además te sugeriría renombrar esos streams, pues los nombres son demasiado parecidos y pueden inducir a un error dificil de encontrar.

```
try (ObjectOutputStream escribir = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(temporalFile));
     ObjectInputStream leer = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(selectedFile))) {
```

Para el futuro, intenta siempre incluir un ejemplo mínimo ejecutable, como el que ves arriba, de forma que cualquiera pueda copiarlo, ejecutarlo y debugearlo localmente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! Tendré en cuenta tu consejo para ayudar a entender mejor el código cuando pida ayuda en el futuro. @RubioRic

Comment: @AndreaSierraRodríguez pero has encontrado el fallo? Espero que sí :-) Suerte con los estudios!

Comment: Si, muchas gracias el fallo estaba en el lugar donde colocaba las líneas de código para eliminar el fichero de objetos principal y renombrar el temporal muchísimas gracias!